Update Sharepoint List with local excel file daily - python Program
Recently in my organisation, we shifted to Microsoft 365 products. Im have created a sharepoint list named "Store Norms and Stock".
I want to update the same list everyday with the local excel file stored in D:Drive using a python program on daily basis.
I have registered an app and got the credentials like client Id, Client Secret and tenant ID please help me how to use this as it was very new for me
Please suggest some sample program
